Northwind Products table
I've got a task to analyze the Northwind sample database from 1996-1998. My task is to analyze the products table so I can provide specific insights and recommendations based on the table to increase profits and reduce costs. i need help since i don't find any logic behind this table and i did'nt find any impressive insights.
I've tried to understand the logic behind the products table and I can't. It seems like there is no logic or some kind of correlation between the columns, why every product has its level for the units in stock column, or for the reorder level.
I've checked for every product's profit, and you would assume that the most profitable products also has lower reorder level so you wont run out of stock but it's not what I found. You would assume that the least profitable products would have a higher reorder level but some of them have high reorder level.
I'm starting to think the catch is that the stock management runs poorly and that's all..
select  
    od.ProductID, c.categoryName, p.productName,    
    p.unitsinstock, p.unitsonorder, p.reorderLevel,
    p.discontinued, p.unitprice buyingPrice,
    sum(od.quantity) 'quantity sold', 
    round((sum((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount)) -sum(p.unitprice * od.quantity)), 2) Product_profit,
    count (o.orderID) ordersCount
from
    Northwind.Orders o
join 
    Northwind.[Order Details] od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
join 
    Northwind.Products p on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
join 
    Northwind.Categories c on c.categoryID = p.CategoryID
group by 
    od.ProductID, c.categoryName, p.productName, p.unitsinstock, 
    p.unitsonorder, p.reorderLevel, p.discontinued, p.unitprice
order by 
    round((sum((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1-od.Discount))-sum(p.unitprice*od.quantity)),2) desc

This is the output, it contains the products table + my calculations:
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

The question is unclear and probably caused by misconceptions. For starters, that data is artificial, meant to demonstrate Microsoft Access and nothing more. That's why the names are so short by the way. It's not from a specific year, nor was the data generated to demonstrate patterns. Second, there's no logic in actual, real world product or order data. The data is what it is. Perhaps a delivery was late. Perhaps the company wants to stock up before sales season. Perhaps the company got it wrong and ordered a ton of products that nobody wants.

In fact, Northwind was considered a bad demo even back in 2000. It was only used in the 1990s because people were already familiar with it from Access demos. It doesn't demonstrate proper database design nor does it use the SQL Server features people would use in real applications. I If you want to analyze demo reporting data, check the WorldWide Importers or the older and smaller AdventureWorks databases. Note there are separate transactional and reporting/data warehouse databases

Both WWI and AdventureWorks were used to demonstrate data mining and analytics over the years, so both have actual, meaningful patterns in their data. WorldWideImportersDW is currently used to demonstrate analytics, data warehousing, Power BI etc. I wouldn't be surprised if its Github repo contains Python scripts as well

Never assume...

+1 to that - don't assume that reorder levels have to do with profitability either. Delivery delays, minimum order counts, sale frequency, minimum delivery costs may matter more than profitability. If something has 1 month lead time, requires 100 items at a minimum and sells 5 items per day, you don't want to put the reorder level at 5, no matter the profitability. If delivery costs eg $1000 + $1/item, you want to place larger orders too

There's no logic or pattern behind that data.
For starters, there's no Northwind company. That's an artificial database, meant to demonstrate Microsoft Access features in the late 1990s. That's why the names are so short for example. It was included in SQL Server back then because people were already familiar with it.
Second, there's no logic in actual, real world product or order data. The data is what it is. Perhaps a delivery was late. Perhaps the company wants to stock up before sales season. Perhaps the company got it wrong and ordered a ton of products that nobody wants.
In fact, Northwind was considered a bad demo even back in 2000. The design itself is bad. It doesn't demonstrate proper database design nor does it use the SQL Server features people would use in real applications. It was replaced in  2005 or 2008 by the AdventureWorks database that included more realistic data, proper reporting schemas and was actually used to demonstrate data mining and analytics. This was later replaced by WorldWide Importers, which demonstrates more advanced analytics and design features. And is a lot larger too.
If you want to analyze demo reporting data, check the WorldWide Importers or the older and smaller AdventureWorks databases. Note there are separate transactional and reporting/data warehouse databases
Both WWI and AdventureWorks were used to demonstrate data mining and analytics over the years, so both have actual, meaningful patterns in their data. WorldWideImportersDW is currently used to demonstrate analytics, data warehousing, Power BI etc. I wouldn't be surprised if its Github repo contains Python scripts as well
You could also use the sample databases used to demonstrate SQL Server's Machine Learning Services feature, which allows creating and using ML models in R and Python. The Samples Github repo contains scripts that create a database with sample bike rental data and use various ML algorithms on it

ok, thank you for the informative comment. tho i still have this project and my task as i said is to increase profits and reduce costs based on the products table. my teacher suggested me to focus on products table, but as i mentioned i didnt find anything really impressive. am i missing something? maybe the thing is just the poor stock managment? thank you.
